# VueJs Quasar - scroll position stuck using Quasar loading component after page change

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

I have a problem using Quasar with VueJs.
When I use Quasar's Loading.show() method, the scroll is stuck when I go to the new page, and the top of the new page is not shown.

In the router/index.js file i have set

```
const router = new VueRouter({
scrollBehavior: () => ({ x: 0, y: 0}),
...
});
```

For example:
In MainLayout.vue (which is the parent component of the index and category page), I have set a watch to show the loading screen when the isLoading flag is true in the state.

```
 watch: {
        isLoading: {
            deep: true,
            handler(isLoading) {
                if(isLoading == true) {
                  Loading.show();
                } else {
                  Loading.hide();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is working fine, but when I have clicked a link to a category page after I have scrolled a little bit, The category page will also retain the previous scroll position.

Is working without the scroll issue with commented out `Loading.show();`

Video from the issue:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d-WaxHazNdZ8bp3_pcN14hcayucUYYUb/view

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this, but I'm not sure if this is the right solution:

```
import { scroll } from 'quasar'
const { getScrollTarget, setVerticalScrollPosition } = scroll

 watch: {
    isLoading: {
        deep: true,
        handler(isLoading) {
            if(isLoading == true) {
              Loading.show();
            } else {
              Loading.hide();

              const el = document.querySelector('.q-page-container')
              const target = getScrollTarget(el)
              const offset = el.offsetTop
              const duration = 0
              setTimeout(() => setVerticalScrollPosition(target, offset, duration), 400);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Documentation https://quasar.dev/quasar-utils/scrolling-utils#scrolling-to-an-element